# javascript jumping character not working

Tags: javascript, 2d, game-physics

I'm having a few issues with my code. Can't get my cube to jump. Take a look at my code and let me know if you can help please.

My left, right and duck abilities all currently work at desired level, but I cannot get my cube to jump. I've been trying for three days and can't find anything online. My javascript is embedded within a  tag in a html page.

```js
var canvas = document.getElementById("gameCanvas");

var ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");

var coinRad = 8;
var coinX = 40;
var coinY = 80;

var x = 20;
var y = 510;
var w = 30;
var h = 50;

var rightPressed = false;
var leftPressed = false;

var ducked = false;
var jumping = false;

document.addEventListener("keydown", keyDownHandler, false);
document.addEventListener("keyup", keyUpHandler, false);

function keyDownHandler(e) {
  if (e.keyCode == 39) {
    rightPressed = true;
  } else if (e.keyCode == 37) {
    leftPressed = true;
  } else if (e.keyCode == 40) {
    ducked = true;
  } else if (e.keycode == 32) {
    jumping = true;
  }
}


function keyUpHandler(e) {
  if (e.keyCode == 39) {
    rightPressed = false;
  } else if (e.keyCode == 37) {
    leftPressed = false;
  } else if (e.keyCode == 40) {
    ducked = false;
  } else if (e.keycode == 32) {
    jumping = false;
  }
}

function drawCube() {
  ctx.beginPath();
  ctx.rect(x, y, w, h);
  ctx.fillStyle = "Green";
  ctx.fill();
  ctx.closePath();
}

function run() {
  ctx.clearRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
  if (leftPressed) {
    if (x > 0) {
      x -= 2.5;
    }
  } else if (rightPressed) {
    if (x < canvas.width - w) {
      x += 2.5;
    }
  }
  if (jumping) {
    y -= 10;
    h -= 10;
  }
  if (ducked) {
    y = 535;
    h = 25;
  } else {
    y = 510;
    h = 50;
  }
  drawCube();
}

setInterval(run, 10);
```

```html
<canvas id="gameCanvas"></canvas>
```

Comment: Please add the HTML/CSS portion of your code to make it easier for us to understand the problem.

Comment: Click the `<>` to create a [mcve]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

because when the run method end, you do this.

```
if (jumping) {
    y -= 10;
    h -= 10;
}
if (ducked) {
    y = 535;
    h = 25;
} else {
    y = 510;
    h = 50;
}
```

even if you change the values from Y and H, their values always change to 510 and 50 respectively, because the **else in ducked condition**.

> Remove this else or find another logic to do the same

Comment: Thank you, this has solved a few bugs. But I can't seem to get my head around letting the character duck when down is pressed, but return to it's normal state when released, and the same for jumping. Would anyone have any links to some good platformer codes?

Answer (score 1):

Additionally, your keyCode check is improperly capitalized for the jumping condition.

```
else if (e.keyCode == 40) {
   ducked = false;
} else if (e.keycode == 32) {  //should be keyCode
   jumping = false;
}
```